# Creating a library with webpack/babel 7, and getting Module build failed: Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.0". upon import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to build a library using webpack 4/babel 7, I'm able to export everything properly to a new create-react-app as it uses babel 7.
But when I'm importing the library to a repository that uses babel 6 I get this

### error

"Module build failed: Error: Requires Babel "^7.0.0-0", but was loaded with "6.26.0". If you are sure you have a compatible version of @babel/core, it is likely that something in your build process is loading the wrong version. Inspect the stack trace of this error to look for the first entry that doesn't mention "@babel/core" or "babel-core" to see what is calling Babel.
    at Array.map ()"

Is there a way to make this work without having the proper babel version for the project that will be importing specific utils from this library?

Shouldn't the build process use babel7 to compile everything so the importing library can use it even with other versions of babel?

### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "Utils.js",
    library: "Utils",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
  },
  target: "node",
  externals: {},
};
```

### .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

### dev dependencies of the library

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
```

Comment: Please include the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: Babel moved from `babel-` to the scoped `@babel` package in v7(?).  I'm guessing you'll need to replace `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` to `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`

Comment: @Phix I do have the proper plugin as my second devDependency, and when it's removed the result is the same. Good catch though! I'll update dependencies

Comment: I'm running into this as well. Any updates? My expectation is that once the library is built for UMD, it shouldn't matter that it was transpiled with babel 7, but that doesn't seem to be the case.